# OpenGL и контекст

Tags: opengles, sdl2

Пишу свой небольшой игровой движок, базирующийся на `opengles` в связке с `sdl2` и столкнулся с проблемой отображения текстур. Я предпологал, что однажды создав тектуру я смогу использовать ее во всех созданных окнах, но, оказалось, что я могу ее отобразить только в том окне, контекст которого был установлен на момент создания окна. Это для меня стало неожиданностью... И, как оказалось, программы, шэйдэры и прочие объекты также напрямую зависят от контекста, чего я не знал. В результате получилась такая ситуация, что графический итем на сцене имеет текстуру (объект, который инкапсулирует текстуру opengl), которую может отобразить только в одно из окон. В связи с этим есть два вопроса:

1) для каждого контекста я должен загружать (`glTexImage2D`) пиксельные данные? Тобишь если мне нежно отобразить 2Мб текстуру в 3 `window` я должен загрузить эти 2Мб для каждого контескта?

2) как правильно организовать прорисовку каждого итема на сцене? На текущий момент при создании итема ему передается некое изображение, из которого получается текстура (объект инкапсулирующий текустуру `opengl`), которая прорисовывается при вызове метода `render`. Сам итем ничего не знает про `opengl`. Как я уже говорил, из-за этого тексура прорисовывается только в одном окне, контекст которого был текущим при создании текстуры. Как мне это обойти?

Comment: мне кажется вы можете создать абстракцию, вроде виртуального контекста, который на самом деле при создании нового контекста не создает новый, а использует единственный. вот тут так сделано только для webgl https://github.com/greggman/virtual-webgl

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не уверен что это возможно для opengl...

Comment: Чтобы не иметь несколько копий текстуры, можно посмотреть в сторону `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_SHARE_WITH_CURRENT_CONTEXT, ...)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это как раз то, что нужно, можете опубликовать это как ответ - это может помочь другим

Comment: Не хочется отвечать на половину вопроса.